# Assign numpy array to pandas mask

Tags: python, pandas, mask

I performed a task on a pandas masked subset:

```
pdxy = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['X','Y','C','CC'])
mask = pdxy[:]['Y']==8

print("pdxy[mask]")
print(pdxy[mask][:10])

pdxy[mask]
       X  Y  C  CC
17    17  8  0   0
18    18  8  0   0
48    48  8  0   0
56    56  8  0   0
63    63  8  0   0
66    66  8  0   0
73    73  8  0   0
87    87  8  0   0
103  103  8  0   0
116  116  8  0   0

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5,random_state=0).fit(pdxy[mask]['X','Y'])
```

afterwards I want to assing the results (clusters and cluster centers) to columns in the pandas dataframe:

```
pdxy.loc[mask]['C']  = np.array(kmeans.labels_)
pdxy.loc[mask]['CC'] = np.array(kmeans.cluster_centers_[kmeans.labels_])[:,0]
```

Unfortunately the DataFrame is not modified, i.e. as before the assignement:

```
print("pdxy[mask] labeled")
print(pdxy[mask][:10]) 

pdxy[mask] labeled
       X  Y  C  CC
17    17  8  0   0
18    18  8  0   0
48    48  8  0   0
56    56  8  0   0
63    63  8  0   0
66    66  8  0   0
73    73  8  0   0
87    87  8  0   0
103  103  8  0   0
116  116  8  0   0
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

accessing a row+column with .loc is done with comma, as [row, col] and not [row][col]

try this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pdxy = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['X', 'Y', 'C', 'CC'])
mask = pdxy[:]['Y'] == 8

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5,random_state=0).fit(pdxy[mask]['X','Y'])

pdxy.loc[mask, 'C']  = np.array(kmeans.labels_)
pdxy.loc[mask, 'CC'] = np.array(kmeans.cluster_centers_[kmeans.labels_])[:,0]

print("pdxy[mask] labeled")
print(pdxy[mask][:10])
```

Comment: and IIRC pandas should also give you a warning when assigning to a copy, something like: `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Comment: Ok, :-) this was to simple. There was no warning and - as far as I understood - loc means always "in place". That I have also to distinguish between [,] and[][] is new to me. Thank You very much! Problem solved.